# How to add, delete or display keys from a keystore without using keytool for AES encryption?

Tags: java, encryption

How can I manage `keystore` in java without using `keytool` command ?

I know how to load the Key Store from the java code, but this is not what I just want, I want to create a Keystore,  Display keys from a keystore or delete a Key entry from a keystore.

Is it possible to do with the java code ?

This is how i am loading the keystore,

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());

    // get user password and file input stream
    char[] password = getPassword();

    java.io.FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
        fis = new java.io.FileInputStream("keyStoreName");
        ks.load(fis, password);
    } finally {
        if (fis != null) {
            fis.close();
        }
    }
```

The instructions are given here to generate a new keystore,

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html

but it just generate an empty `keystore`, not a `keystore` with the key inside it.

Comment: Is `keyStoreName` in the `FileInputStream()` an existing keystore? Or did you try to create a new keystore using that name?

Comment: @SufiyanGhori When you edit the title, [don't add tags](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Tags should be in the tags section. Also note that you shouldn't capitalize everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you have to create an empty keystore before adding a key inside it, and your code wouldn't work because,

```
To create an empty keystore using the above load method, pass null as the InputStream argument.
```

See the following example to see how to pass `null` as argument.

**Creating a Keystore,**

```
public static void createStore(String path, String keyStoreName,
            String storePassword) throws KeyStoreException,
            NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, IOException {
        KeyStore store = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
        char[] password = storePassword.toCharArray();
        store.load(null, password);

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path + keyStoreName);
        store.store(fos, password);
        System.out.println("New Store Created !");
        fos.close();
    }
```

The above code is copied from my repo, [aes-256-java-bks](https://github.com/sufiyanghori/aes-256-java-bks)

According to its description, it has all the features which you need,

> This simple code allows you to encrypt/decrypt any kind of file using
>   AES-256 standard. It uses Bouncy Castle Keystore for Key Management.
>   Beside Encryption, the code allows you to manage your keystore, like
>   Creating a new Keystore, Loading an existing keystore, adding key to
>   an existing keystore, generating new Key with user Password, deleting
>   key from a keystore or displaying keys from given keystore, all these
>   features could be accessed at runtime, all you need to do is execute
>   the program.

The following codes are from the same repository as mentioned above,

**Loading store,**

```
static KeyStore loadStore() throws KeyStoreException,
            FileNotFoundException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            CertificateException {

        KeyStore store = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");

        InputStream keystoreStream = new FileInputStream(keyStoreLocation);
        store.load(keystoreStream, storePassword.toCharArray());
        System.out.println("Key Store loaded!\n");
        return store;
    }
```

For security reasons, you cannot display actual keys from the `keystore`, but you sure could get the list of all the `aliases` of `keys` from the `keystore`,

Check this code,

```
private static void getAliases() throws KeyStoreException,
            FileNotFoundException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            CertificateException, IOException {
        if (store.size() == 0)
            System.out.println("Store is Empty!");
        Enumeration<String> enumeration = store.aliases();
        while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
            String alias = (String) enumeration.nextElement();
            System.out.println("Key Alias: " + alias);
        }
    }
```

**Deleting a Key from keystore,**

```
public static void deleteAlias(String alias) throws KeyStoreException {
        store.deleteEntry(alias);
    }
```

Comment: wonderful answer (Y) +1, however, there is just one error. I am running it in eclipse and it is giving error "BKS not found".

Comment: add bouncy castle jar in your project then. 
In Eclipse, right-click on your project, then properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add External Jars.

Answer (score 1):

Your `FileInputStream`is not reading `"keystorename"` cause it does not exists or it does, but in another location.

According to documentation:

> To create an empty keystore using the above load method, pass null as the InputStream argument.